# Keep Image Ratio The Same as Window Gets Smaller

Tags: html, css, image

I have a 3 column layout done with CSS grid, and I'd like to keep the image ratio consistent when the window reduces in size (the parent container/row has a max-width of 980px).

How do I have it so when the parent container is less than 980px the `<img>` element shrinks and keeps the same ratio - currently the three image containers get narrower but keep the same height.

The example snippet is below and CodePen link is here: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/bGNKRQP

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%}

.section {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4.299rem 0;
    background: red;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 980px;
    background: yellow;
}

.three-column {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.article {position: relative;}

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12rem;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three-column">
      <article class="article">
        <img class="image" src="" alt="">
        <div class="headline-wrapper top-headline-wrapper-1 headline-wrapper-mobile-padding">
          <h3>THIS IS A TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique illum ipsam facere, veniam ullam tempore laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="article">
        <img class="image" src="" alt="">
        <div class="headline-wrapper top-headline-wrapper-1 headline-wrapper-mobile-padding">
          <h3>THIS IS A TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique illum ipsam facere, veniam ullam tempore laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="article">
        <img class="image" src="" alt="">
        <div class="headline-wrapper top-headline-wrapper-1 headline-wrapper-mobile-padding">
          <h3>THIS IS A TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique illum ipsam facere, veniam ullam tempore laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't currently set any `src` to the images, so you had to set up `height` in order for the `<img>` block to be visible.
if the final images are to be in the same propertion, you can just remove the `height` property and they will keep this ratio on smaller resolutions.

if they aren't in the same propertion you might have to use css's @media query for that

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is:

```
.img{
    max-height: 12rem;
    height: 20vw; (or whatever)
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%}

.section {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4.299rem 0;
    background: red;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 980px;
}

.three-column {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.article {position: relative;}

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 12rem;
    height: 20vw;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three-column">
      <article class="article">
        <img class="image" src="" alt="">
        <div class="headline-wrapper top-headline-wrapper-1 headline-wrapper-mobile-padding">
          <h3>THIS IS A TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique illum ipsam facere, veniam ullam tempore laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="article">
        <img class="image" src="" alt="">
        <div class="headline-wrapper top-headline-wrapper-1 headline-wrapper-mobile-padding">
          <h3>THIS IS A TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique illum ipsam facere, veniam ullam tempore laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="article">
        <img class="image" src="" alt="">
        <div class="headline-wrapper top-headline-wrapper-1 headline-wrapper-mobile-padding">
          <h3>THIS IS A TITLE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique illum ipsam facere, veniam ullam tempore laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `height` on your images and once you give them a source, they'll scale proportionately.

```
.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 12rem;
    /* height: 20vw; */
    background: lightblue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/thingevery/pen/PowaKJo